# TCP Server/Client with Timeout

Tags: java, sockets, concurrency

I have created a client and server that communicates to one another properly, but I'm having a problem implementing the timeout feature. If I don't receive any input from the client for 5 seconds, then I should notify the client.
How do I tackle this problem so that waiting for the request is concurrent with the rest of the program?

```
BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(  
            new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));   
...
String clientMove = inFromClient.readLine();
//this is where I wait 5 seconds of a response
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Socket.setSoTimeout()` and catch `SocketTimeoutException`, but why the message to the client? What is the client supposed to do with an unsolicited timeout message? Will it really be listening for that? Or will  it be busy sending the message it is supposed to be sending?

Comment: Im not supposed to close the client, im just supposed to detect a lack of activity. I guess I don't have to notify the client, but I still need to continue the connection.

Comment: I didn't say anything about closing the client.

Comment: Sorry, closing the socket @EJP

Comment: I didn't say anything about closing the socket either. What do these remarks about closing things have to do with my answer?